# How can I get the values of several nested JSON elements

Tags: json, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow that parses a JSON file and at some point I want to loop through a number of array elements that have a common structure like the sample below (***NOTE: every parent element "Fo..." has a different name***)

[image]

In my Power Automate flow there are several steps that extract only the part of the whole JSON file that contains the above structure elements. Using the *xpath* method I save the output to the variable *varXML* and I loop through its contents

[image]

[image]

Here is a more detailed view of the executed flow with input/output data

[image]
[image]

What I would like is inside the *Compose - product_name* step to get the value of *product_name* from the *Compose - Add body* step from each iteration of the loop. The tricky part that I am stuck here, is to use some sort of a *wildcard* for any "body/f***" element, in order to get to the rest of the nested elements below, like the product_name, service_name, link, etc. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have it as XML already, then you don't need to switch back to JSON.

In your `Apply to each`, try the following in a Compose:

```
first(xpath(items('Apply_to_each_-_varXML'), '//product_name/text()'))
```

and

```
first(xpath(items('Apply_to_each_-_varXML'), '//service_name/text()'))
```

Comment: Hi Sam, no need to apologize :) Now I do not get any error msg but the new Compose step with your code does not display any value but is displays a "Click to download" link, which is empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: I missed that you have a property between `body` and `product_name`, it starts with an `f` and you've masked out the rest. Add that into the above updated answer.

Comment: Hi Sam, no problem :) I tried it and still I get the "Click to download" link. I tried to hard-code the "f***" value and it actually returns the product_name whenever it matches the values of "f***". You understood correctly my question. All I need is a wildcard that will act as the generic value of the "body/f?/product_name. I really appreciate your efforts, thank you

Comment: Difficult to do this. Possible via XPATH & XML however I see you have an XML2JSON step before hand. What is the XML? Add it to the question as there might be a better alternative then using JSON.

Comment: Hi Sam, you can see my updated content, thank you

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much Sam. I greatly appreciate your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

The **Advanced Data Operations** connector and the **Json Properties To Name Value Pair Array** operation will do this for you standing on its head.

If you pass it this JSON ...

```
{
  "parentPropertyName1": {
    "property1": "value 1",
    "property2": "value 2",
    "property3": "value 3"
  },
  "parentPropertyName2": {
    "property1": "value 1",
    "property2": "value 2",
    "property3": "value 3"
  }
}
```

... it will produce this result ...

```
[
  {
    "propertyName": "parentPropertyName1",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "property1",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "value 1"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "property2",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "value 2"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "property3",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "value 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "parentPropertyName2",
    "propertyType": "Object",
    "propertyValue": [
      {
        "propertyName": "property1",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "value 1"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "property2",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "value 2"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "property3",
        "propertyType": "String",
        "propertyValue": "value 3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

... that will allow you to loop through the top level set of properties, get the name of each one and then dynamically extract the data from the original object.

https://statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/

https://statesolutions.com.au/trial-licence-sign-up/

##### Result

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi Skin, it looks great but I need to buy the API for it. I am looking for a solution with the tools given by the Power Automate app.